# How can I hide page name in url instead of the query id

Tags: php, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I am new to url rewriting and went through many articles on the net but can't find what I want. I have a URL which looks like `http://example.com/page.php?id=12345` which I want to make it look like `http://example.com/12345`. How can I do so? If there are any good articles to learn that too would be helpful.

**NOTE:** I have other pages where I would like to hide the page extension too.

**Currently here is my .htaccess**

```
# Do not remove this line or mod_rewrite rules and search engine friendly URLs will stop working
RewriteBase /
ErrorDocument 404 http://www.flexo.pe.hu/404error

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^([\w-]+)$ download.php?id=$1 [QSA,L]


<IfModule mod_deflate.c>
  # Compress HTML, CSS, JavaScript, Text, XML and fonts
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/javascript
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/rss+xml
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/vnd.ms-fontobject
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-font
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-font-opentype
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-font-otf
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-font-truetype
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-font-ttf
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-javascript
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xhtml+xml
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xml
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE font/opentype
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE font/otf
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE font/ttf
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE image/svg+xml
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE image/x-icon
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/css
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/javascript
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/plain
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/xml

  # Remove browser bugs (only needed for really old browsers)
  BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4 gzip-only-text/html
  BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4\.0[678] no-gzip
  BrowserMatch \bMSIE !no-gzip !gzip-only-text/html
  Header append Vary User-Agent
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it like this in your root directory,

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^([\w-]+)$ $1.php [QSA,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([\w-]+)$ page.php?id=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Comment: Alright, according to your `.htaccess` you cannot opt for this rule because it is already in use for removing `.php` you have to use something like `id/12323` for this situation.

Comment: Actually I am creating a service like bit.ly/ tiny url/ goo.gl so when I shorten the links I need to have something like `example.com/12345` and also hide the page extension.

Comment: Okay so remove this rule `RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]` in your `.htaccess` and my rule will work without any php extension and value will go to repective file.

Comment: Yes your rule works when I remove that line but I also need to account for other pages where `.php` gets shown

Comment: Please try my edit and remove all the rewrite related rules before trying it!

Comment: @Ayan Glad could help!